# Dropdown box is not working in HTML page using CSS

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, submenu

when I move my cursor to the main menu("for example: Menu 2"), I can see my dropdown list under

[image: example menu]

After when i move my cursor to submenu1 it is not displaying and i can't select it too

here is my sample code:

```
<style type="text/css">

ul#menu, ul#menu ul.sub-menu {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}
ul#menu li, ul#menu ul.sub-menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
/*Link Appearance*/
ul#menu li a, ul#menu li ul.sub-menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #666;
    padding: 5px;
    display:inline-block;
}
/*Make the parent of sub-menu relative*/
ul#menu li {
    position: relative;
}
/*sub menu*/
ul#menu li ul.sub-menu {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
ul#menu li:hover ul.sub-menu {
    display:block;
}

</style>

<div id="menu" align="left">

<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/auth/gs.page'>Menu1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Menu2</a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>
                <a href='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/auth/view.page'>submenu1</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</div>
```

Please provide me idea to resolve it

Comment: i m doing this web application using java

Comment: So,do you think,java causing these problems ?

Comment: Just because the backend is Java, does not mean it's relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing the behaviour you're seeing is actually the submenu disappearing as you move your mouse down from the top-level nav item.

Because of the way you've set it up, there's a small gap (1-3px depending on browser and default user styles) that means it loses the `hover` status (and therefore hides the submenu) as you are "unhovering" the top-level nav item when you go over that gap.

If that is what you're seeing, the easiest way to fix it is to remove the `top` value from `ul#menu li ul.sub-menu` (you have it set to `30px`) and add in equivalent `padding` to the `li` of the submenu to make it look right.

```
ul#menu li ul.sub-menu {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
}


ul#menu li ul.sub-menu li {
     padding-top: 2px;   
}
```

Here's a fiddle with that change: http://jsfiddle.net/adnrw/J44NJ/

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any problems when running your code. Could you clarify what you mean by "not displaying immediately"?

Comment: i can't select the submenu1

Comment: And by select you mean just clicking on it?

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/R9UZv/
I can click submenu1 just fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
ul#menu li:hover ul.sub-menu
```

Should probably be:

```
ul#menu li:hover ul.sub-menu, ul#menu li ul.sub-menu:hover
```